# Inserting data from web page into Ms Access Database stored on Network Drive

Tags: database, ms-access, web

I am very new to using MS Access with web forms.

I want to create a web form (using php) and have the data inserted into an MS Access database. However, the database (.accb file) is currently stored on a network drive.

My question is:
Will the database (.accb file) have to be moved to the web server in order for me to accomplish this? I need to keep the database on the network drive so that everyone in the office can use it. That is, the office staff needs real time access to the database as it is being updated. If the database (.accb file) is moved to the web server, then the non-technical users won't be able to access it. Plus this will create all sorts of security issues with the I.T department.

I am aware that I can create a web app with MS Access. However, this will be very tedious given that the current database is quite old.

Comment: Eh... Does the web server have access to the network drive? If it doesn't, the answer should be very obvious.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I am not sure since I am very new to this. Is it possible for it to have access to the network drive?

Comment: Yes, web servers are just computers, they can have access to network drives. For that to happen, they must be on the same network as the network drive, though, unless you're willing to do some strange things.